# Why do you need to use 'git add .' before using 'git reset --hard'?

Tags: git

When rolling back files, I was occasionally asked this question. I only thought of adding to the staging area can make newly added files follow the modifications when rolling back versions. I just want to know why I need to use `git add .` before `git reset --hard`.

Comment: if you will do a `git reset --hard`, whatever you had _added_ will be cleared up so it's not needed. Check `git help reset` to see how `--mixed`, `--soft` and `--hard` work in terms of how the affect the index.

Comment: You don't (unless you have untracked files you also want to remove - I'd get into the habit of `git add . -N` to start tracking but not stage the content).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to run `git add .` before `git reset --hard`. The staged changes will be discarded by `git reset --hard`.

The only benefit I can think of is that `git add .` stores the contents of all the added files as blob objects, so that the contents have backups in the repository database. However, the file names or paths are not stored. It's not easy to associate the contents with the file names if later you want to restore these discarded changes.

If you want to make a backup of the changes, it is much more helpful to use `git stash` or `git add . && git commit`. Making a new clone or creating a worktree is also an option, so that you can have a clean worktree and leave the changed files in the current repository alone. Even copying the files is more useful than `git add .` before `git reset --hard`.